# Column headers to new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a file picker, which I have and then get the columns of every file and every sheet within that file into a new sheet. So A1 would have file name,B1 sheet name, C1 and down would have column headers (which are A1:?? in all the files Im picking). 
Also some files are large so would having automatic calculation to automatic be helpful?

Also note that I have extra variables in the beggining but not necessarily used.

Here is the code, its a mess:

```
Sub ColumnHeaders()
'includes filling down
'Skips unreadable files

Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer
    Dim r As Range, lr As Long, myrg As Range, z As Range
    Dim boolWritten As Boolean, lngNextRow As Long
    Dim intColNode As Integer, intColScenario As Integer
    Dim intColNext As Integer, lngStartRow As Long
    Dim lngLastNode As Long, lngLastScen As Long

   'Skipped worksheet for file names
   Dim wksSkipped As Worksheet
   Set wksSkipped = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skipped")


     ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

     ' Create a new worksheet, if required
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Headers")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
        Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        wksSummary.Name = "headers"
    End If

     ' Set the initial output range, and assign column headers
    With wksSummary
        Set y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
        Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
        lngStartRow = y.Row
        .Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("File Name", "Sheet Name", "headers")
    End With

'get user input for files to search
Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
If errCheck Then
   Exit Sub
End If
'''
For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary




On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = fileNames(Key)

Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
    ' more working with wb
```

Code should go in here

```
wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
End If

Next 'End of the fileNames loop
Set fileNames = Nothing

 ' Autofit column widths of the report
wksSummary.Range("A1:C1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Reset system settings
With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

I have the picker(a separate function) , I a skipped worksheet incase the file is corrupt, but I obviously am missing the part where to get the headers and sheet names.
Can anyone help?

**UPDATE WITH MATTHEW'S CODE~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**

```
Sub ColumnHeaders()
'includes filling down
'Skips unreadable files

Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As range, intRow As Long, i As Integer
    Dim r As range, lr As Long, myrg As range, z As range
    Dim boolWritten As Boolean, lngNextRow As Long
    Dim intColNode As Integer, intColScenario As Integer
    Dim intColNext As Integer, lngStartRow As Long
    Dim lngLastNode As Long, lngLastScen As Long

'need addition
Dim wsReport As Excel.Worksheet
Set wsReport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Whatever sheet you want to write to


   'Skipped worksheet for file names
   Dim wksSkipped As Worksheet
   Set wksSkipped = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skipped")


     ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

     ' Create a new worksheet, if required
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Headers")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
        Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        wksSummary.Name = "headers"
    End If

     ' Set the initial output range, and assign column headers
    With wksSummary
        Set y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
        Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
        lngStartRow = y.Row
        .range("A1:C1").Value = Array("File Name", "Sheet Name", "headers")
    End With

'get user input for files to search
Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
If errCheck Then
   Exit Sub
End If
'''
For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary




On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = fileNames(Key)

Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
    ' more working with wb


'New addition
Dim iIndex As Integer
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = 1

'Loop through the worksheets in the current workbook.
For iIndex = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count

    'Set the current worksheet
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(iIndex)

    'List out the workbook and worksheet names
    wsReport.range("A" & lRow).Value = wb.Name
    wsReport.range("B" & lRow).Value = ws.Name

    'Start a counter of the columns that we are writing to
    lOutputCol = 3

    'Loop through the columns.
    For lCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        'Write the header
        wsReport.range(Col_Letter(lOutputCol) & lRow).Value = ws.range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value

        'Increment our column counters.
        lOutputCol = lOutputCol + 1
        lCol = lCol + 1
    Next lCol

    'Increment the row we are writing to
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next iIndex



    wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
End If

Next 'End of the fileNames loop
Set fileNames = Nothing

 ' Autofit column widths of the report
wksSummary.range("A1:C1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Reset system settings
With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

TWO FUNCTIONS:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

and

```
Function FileDialogDictionary(ByRef file As Object) As Boolean ' returns true if the user cancels
'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim item As Variant
Dim i As Long
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
file.RemoveAll 'clear the dictionary
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
'Declare a variable to contain the path
'of each selected item. Even though the path is a String,
'the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next
'routines only work with Variants and Objects.
'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
With fd
    'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
    'The user pressed the action button.
    .Title = "Select Excel Workbooks" 'Change this to suit your purpose
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Microsoft Excel files", "*.xlsx,*.xls"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
        For Each item In .SelectedItems 'loop through all selected and add to dictionary
            i = i + 1
            file.Add i, item
        Next item
        FileDialogDictionary = False
    'The user pressed Cancel.
    Else
        FileDialogDictionary = True
        Set fd = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
End With
Set fd = Nothing 'Set the object variable to Nothing.
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a workbook it becomes active so you'll need to create an object that will be the sheet that you are writing to. Somewhere at the top.

```
Dim wsReport As Excel.Worksheet
Set wsReport = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'Whatever sheet you want to write to
```

Code to write out the data. Insert where you put "Code should go in here"

```
Dim iIndex As Integer
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lOutputCol As Long

lRow = 1

'Loop through the worksheets in the current workbook.
For iIndex = 1 To wb.Worksheets.count

    'Set the current worksheet
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(iIndex)

    'List out the workbook and worksheet names
    wsReport.Range("A" & lRow).Value = wb.name
    wsReport.Range("B" & lRow).Value = ws.name

    'Start a counter of the columns that we are writing to
    lOutputCol = 3

    'Loop through the columns.
    For lCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.count
        'Write the header
        wsReport.Range(Col_Letter(lOutputCol) & lRow).Value = ws.Range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value

        'Increment our column counters.
        lOutputCol = lOutputCol + 1
    Next lCol

    'Increment the row we are writing to
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next iIndex
```

And you'll need to add this function

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Hey matthew, thanks, just a quick question before I test it out, some of my files are 500+ mb, is there a way to extract this data without actually opening the workbook?

Comment: I get a compile error, ByRef Argument type Mismatch on this line `wsReport.range(Col_Letter(lOutputCol) & lRow).Value = ws.range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value` specifically on `IoutputCol` . Ill post the updated code.

Comment: No you can't extract the data without opening the workbook.

Comment: This is because `Col_Letter` wants a long and we didn't get lOutputCol declared. You need to declare `Dim lOutputCol as Long`

Comment: Thanks, didnt see that. Would you know why my file picker doesnt find all my files? Is it possible it just looks for .xls format files?

Comment: @Jonathan Not sure about that.  You should create a new post showing just the code that opens your file picker and list the files it is not finding.

Comment: I fixed it, it wasn't search for .csv files. Anyway macro looks good but for some reason its not giving me all the header names just the 3 headers . Seems to be skipping every 2 column headers.

Comment: Ahh, take out `lCol = lCol + 1`  My bad.

Comment: thanks!! still getting some funny errors, using multiple files it overwrites row 1 with the next file. So they are not in separate rows.

Comment: You'll need to move `Dim lRow As Long` and `lRow = 1` above `For Each Key In fileNames`

Comment: Nice!! this is kind of random, but is it possible to delimit the file prior to getting headers?

Comment: Do you means save it as a csv?

Comment: Sorry to make them into 'text to columns'. If they already are in csv format. If in csv format this macro doesn't work too well.

Comment: Not sure.  That might be your next question to post..  Have to run.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, for everything.

Comment: hey Matthew would you know how to put these headers vertically instead of horizontally? and fill down the file and sheet names. So file A name(filled down),sheets(filled down),headers down aswell in the rows. Then repeat for the next file.

Comment: hey Matthew, does this macro take the first line(A1:Z1) of every file and use that as header data? or does it take the first row of full data?

Comment: It takes the first row. `ws.Range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value`  The "1" is the row that it is reporting the headers from.  And it doesn't take it to Z, `For lCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.count` is saying for each column `lCol=1` is starting at A to the last column used `ws.UsedRange.Columns.count`

Comment: is there a way to make it the first row that contains data?

Comment: Yes, look at something like `firstRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, "A").End(xlDown).Row`  then replace the 1 with firstRow

Comment: which one is to be replaced?

Comment: The 1 in `ws.Range(Col_Letter(lCol) & "1").Value` so ws.Range(Col_Letter(lCol) & firstRow).Value